# Onload() function in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm making an end to end test, I want to use `onload()` function to load all the elements before execution but error found *"Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise."* the code below:

```
const loginpage = new loginPage();

cy.visit("/globalview/login",{ timeout: 50000, 


  onLoad: function(contentWindow){

   cy.log('globalview')
   loginpage.FillEmail("");
   loginpage.FillPassword("");
   loginpage.SubmitLogin();

   }
})
```

How can I fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Yields) says `cy.visit() resolves when the remote page fires its load event.`
So it seems you can do your logging actions just after the visit command:

```js
    const loginpage = new loginPage();
    
    cy.visit("/globalview/login",{ timeout: 50000}) 
    
    cy.log('globalview')
    loginpage.FillEmail("");
    loginpage.FillPassword("");
    loginpage.SubmitLogin();

})
```

But this will work if you loginpage's methods are expected to work outside of the cypress loop (i.e. calling other cypress commands)

Comment: thank you very much , the problem is resolved